# Slow video playback older iMac

Tags: mac, firefox, video

I have an iMac from 2006 with an intel core duo @ 2GHz and a RadeonX1600.
Video in VLC or Quicktime play flawlessly without any choppiness, however in the latest Firefox browser, YouTube and pretty much every other website with an inline video will play very choppy at maybe 2fps in fullscreen.

Is it simply because my old hardware is not up to date with the latest software or is there a way I can get YouTube and other players to work fine in fullscreen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Browser video playback largely relies on [Adobe Flash Player](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/4783/adobe-flash-player). Try updating it and see if the playback gets better.

Note that latest versions of Flash Player support only OS X 10.6 or later. If your OS is older than that, you're pretty much stuck.

Note that there are other means to play online videos. For example, youtube supports [HTML5](https://www.youtube.com/html5) for most of the content. You may try to switch to that.

Comment: Both Flash and HTML5 are very choppy. I think HTML5 more so than Flash